# Http request with specified ip

Tags: c#, http

Can I send http request with custom server IP? For examle I have a domain `example.com` (real ip is `1.2.3.4`) but DNS returns secondary ip (`6.7.8.9`). Can I do request to `1.2.3.4` istead of `6.7.8.9`?

Comment: Host names are resolved independently of the Code (I think).  Adding an entry to /etc/hosts or c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts will override the actualy DNS entry.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS issue and not a code issue. If you are explicitly trying to communicate with a given URL, you should not have to use any "hack" to send packets to a predetermined IPAddress. That being said, you should be able to communicate directly with your given IP if necessary, as you wont need DNS if you are targeting a client directly via IPAddress. If you are working locally you might need to update your ARP table.
(edit: Are you trying to spoof your IPAddress or are you trying to connect to a client? Your wording of server/client is not clear, so if my answer is incorrect, please let me know.)

Answer (score -2):

A little time ago.

With this code I test the webservices on 7 diferents nodes:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(server + _tempWS);
            //DataConnection getUser = GetValidUser(server);
            try
            {
                string cook = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityGeneratedValidToken"];
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "FedAuth=" + cook);
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                request.Referer = server ;
                string data = "{\"Pagina\":1,\"Registros\":10,\"Orden\":\"{}\",\"Filtro\":\"{  }\",\"EsInternacional\":false}";
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                request.ContentLength = (long)postBytes.Length;
                request.ContentLength = 0L;
                request.Timeout = 3000;
            }
```

On header set request.Referer to your server.